# deploy toolchains.xml file on heroku

Tags: java, maven, heroku

I've got an app on `heroku`. 
When I try to push changes to `heroku` I get this error

```
remote:        [INFO] Required toolchain: jdk [ vendor='oracle' version='1.9' ]
remote:        [ERROR] No toolchain found for type jdk
remote:        [ERROR] Cannot find matching toolchain definitions for the following toolchain types:
remote:        jdk [ vendor='oracle' version='1.9' ]
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [INFO] Total time: 9.746 s
remote:        [INFO] Finished at: 2017-08-31T18:00:35Z
remote:        [INFO] Final Memory: 24M/80M
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-toolchains-plugin:1.1:toolchain (default) on project java-cloud-sample: Cannot find matching toolchain definitions for the following toolchain types:
remote:        [ERROR] jdk [ vendor='oracle' version='1.9' ]
remote:        [ERROR] Please make sure you define the required toolchains in your ~/.m2/toolchains.xml file.
remote:        [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
remote:        [ERROR]
remote:        [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
remote:        [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
remote:        [ERROR]
remote:        [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
remote:        [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
remote:
remote:  !     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,
remote:        please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to java-cloud-sample.
remote:
```

It seems it cannot find `toolchains` file on `heroku` that should be used for the application. (used by `maven` plugin). `toolchains.xml` looks like this

```
<toolchains>
  <toolchain>
    <type>jdk</type>
    <provides>
      <version>1.9</version>
      <vendor>oracle</vendor>
    </provides>
    <configuration>
      <jdkHome>/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle</jdkHome>
    </configuration>
  </toolchain>
  <toolchain>
    <type>jdk</type>
    <provides>
      <version>1.8</version>
      <vendor>oracle</vendor>
    </provides>
    <configuration>
      <jdkHome>/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle</jdkHome>
    </configuration>
  </toolchain>
</toolchains>
```

I also use `travis-ci` to get code from `github` and there it builds fine (I copy `toolchains.xml` to its `.m2` folder using scripts).

How to add this file to `heroku`?

Comment: Heroku doesn't run the Oracle JDK. Can use "openjdk" as the vendor? If not, what about Azul Zulu (there are undocumented JDK 9 versions on Heroku) https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support#using-the-zulu-jdk

Comment: @codefinger It would be preferrable for oracles, but openjdk is fine too as I just play around with Java 9 in Heroku. But does it use `toolchains.xml` in that case?

Comment: @codefinger by the way to provide toolchains for `openjdk` in heroku while keeping `jdk 9` in my windows machine?